# How to replace Woocommerce "Add to Cart" Button with a Cart Icon and Cart Icon along with custom text?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

Using the below code I was able to change the Text of "Add to Cart" button

```
add_filter( 'add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_single_add_to_cart_text' );                // < 2.1
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_single_add_to_cart_text' );  // 2.1 +

function woo_custom_single_add_to_cart_text() {

    return __( 'My Button Text', 'woocommerce' );

}
```

Similarly, is it possible to replace Add to Cart Button with a Cart Icon or a Cart Icon with Custom Text?

Comment: Try changing button text to '' and set background image for that button in css

Comment: Oh! I should have thought a little more. Thank you for the quick response. Good day!

Comment: @Keyur Is there a way to tweak the above code to achieve the same result. I want to know if it could be achieved this way?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if my answer is the best practice but for sure it is the easiest i can find so far, just go to Woocommerce folder and find "add-to-cart.php" then in it;s loop just replace `esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )` by `sprintf('<i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i>')` -- in case you want to add just a shopping basket icon , just put your html.